# How to access the internet on 64 bit UBUNTU through wine?

Tags: 14.04, wine, 64-bit

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed, and Wine 1.6. I downloaded Wine to be able to run YTD (youtube download manager), an application meant for windows. Sadly, it tells me that there is no internet connection, but on the Wine official site it says that it is supported and fully functional. I need a workaround for this please.

Comment: You could just use a native application like `youtube-dl`... Anyway, where did you download the Youtube Download Manager from?

Comment: Do you use a proxy to connect to the Internet ?

Comment: @Wilf I downloaded it from ytd official site as a .exe install file

Comment: @Benoit no i do not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're a diehard fan of that particular youtube downloader app, save yourself the hassle of setting it up in wine and, like [Wilf](https://askubuntu.com/users/178596/wilf) suggested, just grab a native downloader like youtube-dl instead.

Instructions:

1. Open a terminal window by pressing ctrl+alt+t
2. Enter the following commands to install youtube-dl

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8 -y`
   `sudo apt-get update`
   `sudo apt-get install youtube-dl`
3. Download your videos by entering the following command into any terminal window

   `youtube-dl http://youtube.com/watch?v=[VIDEO_CODE]`

   e.g.

   `youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxD_kWK8A5M`
4. For more advanced usage instructions, like downloading videos in a particular format, or downloading multiple videos at once, [see this article](http://www.tecmint.com/install-youtube-dl-command-line-video-download-tool/).

Comment: As a matter of fact I have already tried it, I want to download entire playlists in a selected format, and I have been searching for a while about how to choose from available formats but I have not been lucky in my search

Comment: Try [this](http://xmodulo.com/2013/07/how-to-download-youtube-playlist-in-linux.html).